# Range for loop through forwarded iterable

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-passing, c++14

Suppose I have the following situation

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& arg)
{
    for (auto elem : arg) // ***
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

where arg is iterabe (vector or initializer list etc) . I'm interested in line *** : Which of the following is better to do :

```
auto elem
auto& elem
`const` of the above
```

I suppose option (3) is covered by argument deduction (auto will put a const there if that's what's needed). Also does the fact that `func` is called like so

```
func(std::forward<T>(arg));
```

change anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `auto` for the variable declaration in a range-based `for` loop is nearly **always** wrong. It is only ever correct if the range is guaranteed to use built-in object which are not mutated. I would not normally use `auto` here (to be fair, I would also not range-based `for` in the first place but prefer an algorithm).

Using `auto&` constraints the result of `*it` for an iterator `it` over the range to be `T&` or `T const&` for some suitable type `T`. For example, it wouldn't allow iterating over a `std::vector<bool>`. If the elements are allowed to be mutated, that is a reasonable option. Using `auto const&` constraints the results of `*it` to be either an lvalue or have a copy constructor and will prevent the range to be mutated. That may be a reasonable choice depending on use.

In general, the default choice shall be `auto&&` as that arranges for no constraint on the results of `*it` other than not being `void`.

So, in summary:

- `for (auto elem: arg)` if the elements have to be built-in and are not mutated.
- `for (auto& elem: arg)` if the elements are lvalues and are allowed to be mutated.
- `for (auto const& elem: arg)` if the elements are lvalues but not mutated.
- `for (auto&& elem: arg)` in all cases where it doesn't matter. I'd think always using `auto&&` is OK.

Comment: If you want a local copy to mutate, `auto` is correct as well.  An unusual requrement, but can exist.  Or if you want a local copy that other operations on the container elements won't mutate, `const auto` (note danger of invalidating iterators: elememt modification proof, not container-itself modification proof sometimes).  These are both somewhat rare, the second moreso.

Comment: Not so sure about the last suggestion (always use `auto&&`). I feel it would sometimes shadow bugs not to use `auto const&`. Consider the following, and let's say the author forgot one `=`: `std::vector<std::map<int, int>> v; for (auto&& m : v) { if (m[1] = 2) { } }`. With `auto&&`, this will create a run-time error, whereas `auto const&` makes it a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on what's in the container.

If the container's values are large, heavyweight objects, using a reference would be better because it avoids making a copy of it.

On the other hand, if a container's values are just small values, especially native datatypes, an explicit copy will encourage better compiler optimization, since the compiler can assume that, during the iteration, the current value being used cannot be modified via another reference or pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want to do and what a type of T is.

You should use:

```
for (auto elem : arg)
{
      // do stuff
}
```

when T is a primitive type (cheap to copy) and you do not want to modify the 'arg' collection.

You should use:

```
for (auto& elem : arg)
{
      // do stuff
}
```

if you want to modify the 'arg' collection.

You should use:

```
for (const auto& elem : arg)
{
      // do stuff
}
```

when T is not a primitive (expensive to copy), and you promise not to change the 'arg' collection.